# Bootstrap: form-group vs input-group, what is the difference?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap v3, what is the difference between the `form-group` and `input-group` classes and when would you use one or the other?  I've been using `form-group` around a couple text inputs and when I switch the class in the outer div from `form-group` to `input-group` and vice versa nothing seems to change.

I've tried searching for the difference between the two but have not turned up much except [this snippet on the bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-example) that says:

> Do not mix form groups directly with input groups. Instead, nest the input group inside of the form group.

However, the form-group example just above it does not use input-group in it, so I'm confused where it fits in and when to use it.  Thanks.

Comment: The "Transfer Cash" example in the [Inline Form examples (v3.3 docs)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline) just below the part of the docs the OP quoted has a nice example of both. Also [nice answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837392/1028230) on a duplicate question posted after this one.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but I had the same question. An input-group is used when you want to wrap tags around an input field, so for example if you wanted to prepend a currency symbol or postpend some decimal figures. Otherwise an input-group isn't needed:

```
<div style = "padding: 100px 100px 10px;">
   <form class = "bs-example bs-example-form" role = "form">         
      <div class = "input-group">
         <span class = "input-group-addon">$</span>
         <input type = "text" class =" form-control">
         <span class = "input-group-addon">.00</span>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Source - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_input_groups.htm

Answer (score -3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row ">
  
  <div >

<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="selectbasic">Select Basic</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Option one</option>
      <option value="2">Option two</option>
      <option value="3">Option three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput">Text Input</label>  
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md">
  </div>

 <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput">Text2 Input</label>  
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md">
  </div>
  
 
<!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->

  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="radios">Inline Radios</label>
  <div class="col-md-2"> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-0" value="1" checked="checked">
      Yes
    </label> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-1">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="2">
      No
    </label> 
  </div>
</div>

  

</fieldset>
</form>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</div>
         


</body>
</html>
```